# How to deal with type checking for optionally None variable, Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pylance

In the example below. The init method of MyClass defined the attribute `self._user` has optionally the type of `UserInput` and is initialized as `None`. The actual user input should be provided by the method `set_user`. For some practical reason, the user input cannot be provided to the method `__init__`. After giving user input, other methods `method_1` and `method_2` can be called.

Question to professional Python programmers: do I really need to add `assert ... not None` in every method that uses `self._user`? Otherwise,  VS Code `Pylance` type checking will complain that `self._user` might be `None`.
However, I tried the same code in PyCharm with its built-in type checking. This issue is not raised there.

And as professional Python programmers, do you prefer the `Pylance` type checking in VS Code, or the built-in type checking in PyCharm?

Thanks in advance.

```py
class UserInput:
    name: str
    age: int


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._user: UserInput | None = None

    def set_user(self, user: UserInput):  # This method should be called before calling any methods.
        self._user = user

    def method_1(self):
        assert self._user is not None  # do I actually need it
        # do something using self._user, for example return its age.
        return self._user.age  # Will get warning without the assert above.

    def method_2(self):
        assert self._user is not None  # do I actually need it
        # do something using self._user, for example return its name.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's safest and cleanest if you keep the `assert`s in. After all, it is up to the user of your class in which order he calls the instance methods. Therefore, you cannot guarantee that `self._user` is not `None`.

Comment: Hi @DarkMath, thanks for your answer. But based on @blueteeth answer, the `assert` statement is not meant for the production environment, only for dev.

Comment: Hi @aura, in my opinion it is not bad to have `assert` statements in production code. I do this in every case that I expect to never occur. Custom exceptions like the `NoUserExcpetion` are nice for business logic, but they are only useful if the client that uses your class can handle them correctly. I prefer `AssertionError`s in each case where the client have no chance to react to the occured error. This is the case in your example If you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bad practice to use `assert` in production code. When things go wrong, you get lots of `AssertionError`, but you don't have any context about why that assertion is being made.

Instead I would catch the issue early, and not handle it later. If `set_user()` should be called earlier, I'd be tempted to put the user in the `__init__` method, but the same principle applies.

```py
@dataclass
class UserInput:
    name: str
    age: int


class NoUserException(TypeError):
    pass


class MyClass:
    # Or this could be in the __init__ method
    def set_user(self, user: UserInput | None):
        if not user:
            raise NoUserException()
        self._user: user


    def method_1(self):
        # do something using self._user, for example return its age.
        return self._user.age

    def method_2(self):
        # do something using self._user, for example return its name.
        return self._user.name
```

You already stated that `set_user` will be called first, so when that happens you'll get a `NoUserException` if the user is None.

But I'd be tempted to not even do that. If I were writing this, I'd have no NoneType checking in `MyClass`, and instead not call `set_user` if the user was None.

```
m = MyClass()
user = ...
if user:
   m.set_user(user)
   ... # anything else with `m`
else:
   # here is where you would get an error
```

Comment: Hi @blueteeth, thanks for your answer. However, in my work, the `__init__` method cannot have the `user` input parameter.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that. The same applies, but then I'd be tempted to not even let the code go so far.

Comment: I see you removed the `__init__` method. But does it violate the rule that "any attribute (here is `self._user`) should be defined in `__init__` method?

Comment: It's just an example. Linters might not like it, but it won't stop working: `should != must`. Why can't you edit the `__init__` method? This implementation implies that multiple different users are going to be set, whereas I would always go for multiple classes in that case.